# Why isn't my visual state manager working for pointerover?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Here is my markup

```
<Grid Height="50"  x:Name="TextGrid">
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TestGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TestGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<Grid.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EntranceThemeTransition></EntranceThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>

</Grid.Transitions>
<Grid x:Name="TestGrid" Background="SeaShell">
    <TextBlock Text="test" x:Name="testTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="OrangeRed" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

I can't figure out why the pointer over effect isn't working.

Comment: a.) I don't think WinRT TextBlock has a Background property, this will require a quick template edit to add a way to support it. b.) You'll want a ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames in a DoubleAnimation instead of an ObjectAnimation. Can provide example after lunch in a bit ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I updated it and nested it in a grid.  I know I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to make ya wait a bit longer before I can provide an example. I might suggest a relatively simple route though to accomplish your goal though. Just steal a HyperlinkButton template, remove all the VisualStates except the PointerOver and edit it to your needs. Than your states will work (as I assume you copy/pasted those parts from a template already) since the type of animations you're trying to use are aimed at template contents and not dependencies. Otherwise, I should have more time free up in a couple hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is it that we are looking at right now? I see some visual states, but you're not saying what they are in. I believe a button goes to a `PointerOver` state when you hover your mouse cursor on top of it, so it should work if this is a button template, but if this is just a `UserControl` - you actually need to handle a pointer event and make a call to VisualStateManager to transition to `PointerOver` state for your control and then back to the other state when the pointer exits the control.